# Get Excel to display full values

Tags: excel, vba, ssis, format

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a range of values which are numbers that go to up 20 decimal places, unpivoted from another sheet using the trick from [here](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/transposing-a-dataset-with-a-pivottable/).

The trouble is the cells are only displaying 10 digits so, for example, even though the value is 5.46827166811115 it is showing as 5.468271668.

I've tried setting the format to text but it still wants to treat it as a number, the number of decimal places varies so I can't use a fixed #.### format. The only way I can get it to show is to format the cells as text and to just select and then click in the entry box for each and every cell!

It then shows a warning that the number in the cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe but at least it's showing the full value.

I did find a VBA script that just did something stupidly simple like cell.Value = cell.Value for the selection which seemed to work but I can't find it anymore and I can't reproduce that now.

Surely there's an easier way to do this? It wouldn't matter so much but when I import this data through SSIS into a VARCHAR(MAX) it's getting the truncated values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-pend a single apostrophe `'` to the data. In many cases, this is more effective than setting the cell format to text.

Comment: That means dealing with the apostrophe when reading it but your suggestion did give me the idea which does work which is simply to append an empty string, so set Bx to = ""&(Ax)

Comment: Excel ignores the apostrophe when referencing the cell in formulas. Likewise, getting the cell value in VBA using `Range.Value`, `Range.Value2`, and `Range.Text` returns only the content - sans apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

You could format the cell as text and the do an `.AutoFit` so the cell expands to show all the cell content, like this:

```
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

that will expand the A:A cell so all its content is visible.

Answer (score 0):

try formatting with `#.000` instead of `#.###`, but if your problem is that Excel is dropping precision on you, you could try multiplying the value by 10^20, then dividing by 10^20 on the SQL side.

found more info:
[here](http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/261104-increase-excel-precision.html)

looks like Excel is limited to 15 digits of precision, multiplying by 10^20 doesn't increase the precision, so you can treat it like text or split the remaining digits into another column and combine them back with SSIS or SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the IMEX=1 to your connection string?  That keeps SSIS from trying to figure out the data from the first few rows.

Also, what about using a decimal datatype instead of varchar(max)